# renovating a bathroom to add wet room for tub & shower

Tags: bathroom

Thinking of  remodeling existing  11x 7 foot bathroom with bathtub & shower in one wet area. Not sure if the size of this area  5 ft x 4.5 ft is adequate,  without resulting in having to clean the bathtub every time a shower is taken? What is a "recommended space " so that the bathub will not be splashed when only a shower is taken?
      Also  concerned about if the shower drain will be adequate enough, without water overflowing into the rest of the bathroom ?

Your advice with these 2 questions will greatly be appreciated!

Thank You,
 George

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram showing your plans would be extremely helpful.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense - 5x4.5 wouldn't even fit the bathtub for bathrooms I do.

Comment: Maybe consider putting a shower door so there is nothing splashing out at all.

Answer (score 1):

The size sounds large enough for a shower. Have you thought about a ceiling mounted shower? The shower coming straight down there may be less splashing compared to a wall mounted shower. I usually install 2" shower drains but have installed 1-1/2". I find the size of the drain opening like a larger 4" square grate compared to a standard 2" round makes the biggest difference with a shallow pan or slope, more area less water back up.